# Assign all data to all slots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a better way to assign my data to all my slots, without needing to bind this on each individual slot?

So currently i'm doing:

```html
<slot name="header" :data="this._data">
    <header>
        <h2>{{ header }}</h2>
        <p>{{ subtitle }}</p>
    </header>
</slot>
```

This in order to use the data I must do this:

```html
<finance-calculator class="app" vehicle-id="1815981">
    <template #header="data">{{ data.data.header }}</template>
</finance-calculator>
```

I tried to use the `render` method to assign the data however this doesn't appear to work at all:

```js
render() {
    const data = this._data;
    return this.$scopedSlots['header']({
        test: 'hello'
    });
},
```

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can use `$data` to refer to the data object of a component. Like this:

```
<slot name="header" :data="$data">
    <header>
        <h2>{{ header }}</h2>
        <p>{{ subtitle }}</p>
    </header>
</slot>
```

```
<finance-calculator class="app">
    <template #header="{data}">{{ data.header }}</template>
</finance-calculator>
```